# Android: Why is it not possible to install the a second apk with same packagename on one phone?

Tags: android, package

Hope the question is clear enough. I don’t find something appropriate here or somewhere in the web which explains me why is it not possible. Maybe some of you can help me out?

It’s a general question with no problem in background (however you can always change the name of the package to avoid this) but I want to understand the idea behind this.

**[Update]** 
Maybe I got a wrong expression about the package name? I think a package name is used to create logical units together. So, e.g. I check a slider and a checkbox alone I create a package name like de.test to put these projects to the same package name. And if I create some customer project I use a package name like de.company for all my projects. But if it’s the package name only for create a unique modifier this though is wrong…

Comment: a package is unique... why would you have 2 packages that are the same.. thats redundant and confusing.

Comment: When I create some projects just for testing some functionality I give them an appropriate name (like SharedPreferences) and with a look on the package name I see if this project is for testing or not (sure I can always give the project a Test prefix but why should I?). So I create two “standard” package names like de.company for all customer projects and de.test for all test projects. That’s my though behind.

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation is that the package name represents the unique identifier for the application. Its given in the google documentation for mainfest file

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and a line from that page. This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) will also give you more idea.

> It names the Java package for the application. The package name serves
>   as a unique identifier for the application.